# How to hide Non-Authorative answer while doing nslookup

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, nslookup

I have an Azure web app and also added a new custom domain with a wildcard certificate. But when I am doing nslookup, it shows the .azurewebsites.net in aliases with IP address.

Can we hide this Non-Authorative answer, as for VM it does show any data, it is showing for Web app only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can hide this data, Non-authoritative name servers do not contain original source files of domain’s zone. They have a cache file for the domains that is constructed from all the DNS lookups done previously. If a DNS server responded for a DNS query which doesn’t have original file is known as a Non-authoritative answer.

For example, we query for DNS records of domain tecadmin.net and Google’s open DNS server 8.8.8.8 responded for this query which doesn’t contain domain’s original zone files. This answer is known as a Non-authoritative answer.

```
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   tecadmin.net
Address: 104.27.189.217
Name:   tecadmin.net
Address: 104.27.188.217
```

You can read about "How DNS works" in [this](https://serverfault.com/a/720535/519350) link.

Additional reference:

Hope it helps.